# assign Episerver property value to css class inside asp.net tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, episerver

```
<EPiServer:Property PropertyName="Propertyx" runat="server" />
```

What's the right syntax to assign an episerver property value to a asp label class? e.g.

```
<h1 class= ....> Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question, but if you want to render a h1 with a class:

```
<EPiServer:Property PropertyName="YourProperty" CustomTagName="h1" CssClass='<%# CurrentPage["YourCssClassProperty"] %>' runat="server" />
```

Comment: Thanks Johan. Problem is I have two "nested" EPiServer properties, so I would have to replace yourcssclass from your snippet by another Property expression:
`<EPiServer:Property PropertyName="YourProperty" CssClass="<EPiServer:Property PropertyName="SecondProperty" runat="server" />"
runat="server" />`
Unfortunately this is not the correct syntax, Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: The CssClass property is bindable, please see my updated answer. However depending on how you databind stuff on your page, you might need to call this.DataBind() in code-behind, or even better just for the property control (then you need to add an ID so you can access it from code).